# SonarRunner: Unable to find file warning

Tags: android, android-studio, sonarqube, lint, sonar-runner

I have configured an Android sample app project in order to detect **Lint** errors and include them into **SonarQube** server. Everything works fine but when I explicitly introduce an error in `AndroidManifest.xml` (deleting the `allowBackup` line), the **sonar-runner** execution shows the next warning:

```
16:33:57.681 WARN  - Unable to find file C:\Code\Android\SampleApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml to report issue
```

The path is OK, so that is not the problem. Moreover, the error is located properly when I make `gradle lint` and written into `lint-results.xml` file:

```
<issue
    id="AllowBackup"
    severity="Warning"
    message="Should explicitly set `android:allowBackup` to `true` or `false` (it&apos;s `true` by default, and that can have some security implications for the application&apos;s data)"
    category="Security"
    priority="3"
    summary="Missing `allowBackup` attribute"
    explanation="The allowBackup attribute determines if an application&apos;s data can be backed up and restored. It is documented at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#allowBackup

By default, this flag is set to `true`. When this flag is set to `true`, application data can be backed up and restored by the user using `adb backup` and `adb restore`.

This may have security consequences for an application. `adb backup` allows users who have enabled USB debugging to copy application data off of the device. Once backed up, all application data can be read by the user. `adb restore` allows creation of application data from a source specified by the user. Following a restore, applications should not assume that the data, file permissions, and directory permissions were created by the application itself.

Setting `allowBackup=&quot;false&quot;` opts an application out of both backup and restore.

To fix this warning, decide whether your application should support backup, and explicitly set `android:allowBackup=(true|false)&quot;`"
    url="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#allowBackup"
    urls="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#allowBackup"
    errorLine1="    &lt;application
"
    errorLine2="    ^"
    quickfix="studio,adt">
    <location
        file="C:\Code\Android\SampleApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml"
        line="5"
        column="5"/>
</issue>
```

What can be causing this warning and why the error is not shown in SonarQube server?

Comment: Hi frapen, did you find the solution for this ? I tried the below answer by @benzonico but still have the issue.

Comment: Yes, @Henry, the solution given by benzonico worked for me and solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is shown because the `xml` file is not indexed by the platform. As a consequence the android lint plugin tries to report your issue but the file cannot be found on the server side.

This is a current limitation of the platform that should be addressed very soon.

To workaround this limitation and index your `xml` file you can either :

- install the xml plugin (which will force indexation of xml files)
- if you are using SonarQube 5.1 you can set `sonar.import_unknown_files` to true.

(you can also have a look at this [thread](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Importing-of-any-file-in-5-1-td5033660.html) for a little more info)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I have tried both workarounds without success.

Comment: I am using SonarQube 5.1. Firstly, I have installed XML plugin from **Settings > System > Update Center > [XML](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/XML+Plugin)**, restarted server and execute `gradle sonarRunner`. Lastly, I wrote `sonar.import_all_files=true` in `sonar-project.properties` file and tried again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well setting is `sonar.import_unknown_files`  not `sonar.import_all_files`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Followed the solution suggested by @benzonico and still faced the issue. I then found out my issue. In the sonar.sources, i just mentioned the 'src' path, but forgot about the 'res' (in my project i have res outside src). I then put both the paths to the sonar.sources. Then all the xml files got indexed. Thanks @benzonico.

Comment: Yes, it's a common mistake when configuring the project, and it's sometimes hard to realize. Thanks for sharing your problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you will need to index the .xml files of your project:
- Add the resource path to the src property 
- Make sure that the xml plugin is installed on your SQ server
- Make sure that the language of your project is set to java and xml

At this point, the SQ shall index the xml files, they must be displayed in the dashboard.

The problem then is that the 'severity' attribute of your issue is only "warning". It seems that the sonar plugin does not import warnings but only errors.

You might need to create a lint configuration file to override the default configuration, it should look like this:

lint.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="AllowBackup" severity="error" />
</lint>
```

then in the android section of your build.gradle:

```
lintOptions {
    lintConfig = file("${projectDir}/lint.xml")
    showAll true
    abortOnError false
    ...
}
```

[EDIT] It seems that the gradle plugin has an option to treat warnings as errors. I have not tested it but you may try the followin instead of using a custom lintConfig file

```
lintOptions {
    warningsAsErrors true
    showAll true
    abortOnError false
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on SonarQube v6.0, and I found a official solution on [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Analyse+Maven+pom.xml+Files):

**Configuration**

In order to execute the rules during analysis, the feature requires SQ to import XML files.
This can be done using two distinct approaches :

1.**Install XML plugin** : the [XML plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/XML+Plugin), on top of other features, indexes XML files.

2.**(SQ 5.1+) Import unknown files** : turn on the [import of unknown files](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code#AnalyzingSourceCode-Unrecognizedfiles) for your projects by setting property "sonar.import_unknown_files" to "true".

**For approache 1:**

Still show "Unable to find file warning" error message.

**Workaround:**

1.Like @Henry says: add 'res' folder to sources: `sonar.sources=src, res`

2.Remove `sonar.language=java` from configuration, because SQ is support mutil language now. If you don't remove language, SQ will only process java files.When you remove and run, some logs will output and looks like:

```
11:06:30.781 INFO  - Index files
11:06:31.016 INFO  - 120 files indexed
11:06:31.029 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Android Rules
11:06:31.029 INFO  - Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
```

**What about approache 2?**

It works, but lots of unknown files will be index. Even included some png, jpg files, and "Lines of Code" in SQ will also contains these unknown files. So, I don't really recommand this way!